# How to connect android app to raspberry pi so that it will reflect all the data from sensors on to the android app

Tags: android, django, raspberry-pi

There are some sensors that will send real time data to raspberry pi.Raspberry pi will process that data and stored it into the database which is local to raspberry pi.So, is there any API that can be used to access the data from database which is stored in  raspberry pi on an android app.
Is it possible to use PiUi or django and if not then what should i use?

Answer (score 0):

I would post/save the data sent to the rPI into a web server, then using a HTTP protocol, connect the android app to the server and download the relevant data.

But that's me, other than doing some complex things; that's the 'easy' way to do it.